# Taking supremum from integral

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, quantum-mechanics, greens-function

By solving Schrodinger equation $H\psi = E\psi$ using Green function I get

$$\psi(x) = \int G(x,x')E\psi(x') dx' $$

by taking abs of $\psi$

$$|\psi(x)| \leq E \int |G(x,x')\psi(x')|dx' \leq E \sup_{x'}(\psi(x')) \int |G(x,x')|dx'  $$

Why is it possible to take out $\psi$ from the integral with $\sup$?

And what does it mean

$$\frac{|\psi(x)|}{\sup_{x'}(\psi(x'))} = |\psi(x)|_\infty$$

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: $\sup_{x'} \psi(x')$ is a constant, the supremum of $\psi$ over all $x'$ in its domain, and $\psi(x') \le \sup_{x'} \psi(x')$.

Comment: Ohh ok.. So in this case sup will just find the maximum value of $\psi$ which is the amplitude of the wave and the second part of the question is just the norm of $\psi$ normalized by norm of $\psi(x')$?

Comment: It should be $\sup_{x'}|\psi(x')|$, not $\sup_{x'} \psi(x')$ (since $\psi(x')$ is a complex number in general). Also, usually $|\psi|_\infty$ is defined to be $\sup_{x'}|\psi(x')|$, so I'm not really sure where than last equation is coming from. Maybe you can provide some further context?

Comment: Yes, I frogor to write $| |$, and I took it from here

https://youtu.be/0y1QEeOoko4?t=637

Comment: @YoniBerkovitch, I'm just now seeing your reply (since you didn't @ me). Looking at the video, it seems that $|\psi(x)|_\infty$ is simply *defined* to be $\frac{|\psi(x)|}{\sup_{x'}|\psi(x')|}$ (so it's just a real number between 0 and 1).